# Only allow numbers to be put in textbox if another texbox is >0

Tags: excel, vba

I want to stop a textbox from getting a number entered if the first textbox is greater than 0.00.  If textbox112 is >0 then textbox 113 must be empty.

I tried different codes to get it to work without luck.

```
Private Sub TextBox113_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If Trim(TextBox112.Text) <> "" Then
        If Len(TextBox113.Text) = 0 Then
            Select Case KeyAscii
                Case 45, 46, 48 To 58
                    'Do nothing. The - sign, decimal and any number is allowed in first position.

                Case Else
                    Beep
                    KeyAscii = 0

            End Select
        Else
            Select Case KeyAscii
                Case 48 To 58
                    'Do nothing. Any number is allowed

                Case 46
                    If InStr(TextBox113.Text, ".") > 0 Then
                        Beep
                        KeyAscii = 0
                    Else
                        'Do nothing.  One and only one decimal point allowed.
                    End If

                Case Else
                    Beep
                    KeyAscii = 0

             End Select
        End If
    Else
        ' I THINK I NEED CODE HERE TO NOT ALLOW ENTRY
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the first message box only permitted to accept a numeric value?  i.e. if you typed in "Wow", it would not allow it?

Comment: Sorry, textbox, not message box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it does what you want ...

```
Private strPreviousValue As String

Private Sub TextBox112_Change()
    Dim bEnabled As Boolean, strText As String

    strText = TextBox112.Text

    If Len(strText) > 0 And Not IsNumeric(strText) And strText <> "-" Then strText = strPreviousValue

    bEnabled = True

    If IsNumeric(strText) Then
        If strText > 0 Or strText = "-" Then
            bEnabled = False
        End If
    End If

    TextBox113.Enabled = bEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox112_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    strPreviousValue = TextBox112.Text
End Sub
```

... my only concern is that I don't have a full grasp of your requirement.  Also, I didn't clear the 2nd text box, I just disabled it for demo purposes, that can be changed obviously.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me.  I like the code I have for TextBox112 and TextBox113.  If you "Group" two OptionButtons you can only click one of them. Click on one and it goes to "True" and the other is "False."  If you click the other it becomes "True" and the first one becomes "False."  I want to do that with TextBoxes just like I can with Option Buttons.  I hope that get me needs across better.

Comment: @Bzltyr so why are you asking the question if you like your code? I’m confused.

Comment: I like the code for formatting each textbox.  The code I can't write is to limit a numeric value in only one of the two cells.  If textbox112 has a number in it tetbox113 must be empty.  If I put a number in textbox113 the number in textbox112 is deleted. So the last textbox that I enter a number keeps the number and the other is deleted.

Comment: @Bzltyr yep, so what I gave you essentially does what you’re asking, you just need to adapt it further to suit your requirement for both textboxes. Like I said, I just disabled the text box instead of clearing it because it demonstrated it better. Clearing is a dangerous approach as well so you may want to rethink that. Also, why even have two textboxes? Why not have a radio button/option to indicate what is going into that field? If I was writing I to one field and the it was deleted because I wrote in the other field and then I wanted the old value back, I’d be pretty annoyed as a user.

Comment: Thanks, Skin.  I will give your code a try.  Your radio button is a good idea.